wsl uninstall on Windows Server
I've installed WSL on Windows Server 2019. While the Microsoft documentation had some gaps, it seemed to work fine. I have a separate issue where I want to completely remove WSL and start over for clarity and to isolate any setup issues.
Per Microsoft this seems pretty straightforward:
wsl -l (provides a list of installed distributions)
and
wsl -unregister  (removes that distribution)
Both of these options (command or PowerShell) just return the basic help and/or invalid command
So I'm stuck and can't find anyone that has had a similar issue or any way to remove WSL.

This really sounds like a question for a Windows forum - however one thing to note is that the unregister command needs TWO dashes i.e. wsl --unregister name_of_distro. See for example Unregister or uninstall a Linux distribution

This question is similar to: How to uninstall the WSL installation of Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows 10?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I found the correct answer on a GitHub issue post. It's not very well documented but the solution on Server 2019 was
wslconfig /l
And
wslconfig /u
